# Xamarin application is Building in Debug mode but not Building in Release mode for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is Error log what i found while i Build application in Release mode

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task LinkAssemblies: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty::Create(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2>,!!1,Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/ValidateValueDelegate`1<!!1>,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/BindingPropertyChangedDelegate`1,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/BindingPropertyChangingDelegate`1<!!1>,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/CoerceValueDelegate`1)' (defined in 'Xamarin.Forms.Labs, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Forms.Labs, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. (XYZ.Droid)

Comment: Did you try using different "Linker behavior" options? Also check if different options are set for Debug and Release. Please note that you must test the build fully after playing around with Linker Options.

Comment: I'm having the identical problem. Switching off linking makes this problem go away, but your .apk is enormous. It's not a solution.

Comment: @Ahmed Salman Tahir Thanks

Comment: @ Mick Byrne Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve this problem by uncheck SDK Linking from Droid option,
now I can build my application in Release mode. But i found that if you do unCheck SDK linking it will create ur .apk file too big in size.
But at least I able to create Release build.